# web-browser displays nothing when parsing xml file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to parse a simple xml-file using java-script. When I loaded the file into the webrowser "Chrome" the page displays nothing.
[image]

Please let me know what is my mistake.

**xml File**:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<company>
    <employee id="001" >John</employee>
    <turnover>
        <year id="2000">100,000</year>
        <year id="2001">140,000</year>
        <year id="2002">200,000</year>
    </turnover>
</company>
```

**JAvaScript Parser**:

```
Read XML in Microsoft Browsers</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlDoc;
function loadxml()
{
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = readXML; /* to be notified when the state changes */
  xmlDoc.load("C:\Users\Amr\Desktop\files\xml.xml");
}

function readXML()
{
   if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4)
   {
    //Using documentElement Properties
    //Output company
    alert("XML Root Tag Name: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);

    //Using firstChild Properties
    //Output year
    alert("First Child: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[1].firstChild.tagName);

//Using lastChild Properties
//Output average
alert("Last Child: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[1].lastChild.tagName);

//Using nodeValue and Attributes Properties
//Here both the statement will return you the same result
//Output 001
alert("Node Value: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].attributes[0].nodeValue);
alert("Node Value: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue);

//Using getElementByTagName Properties
//Here both the statement will return you the same result
//Output 2000
alert("getElementsByTagName: " + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue);

//Using text Properties
//Output John
alert("Text Content for Employee Tag: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].text);

//Using hasChildNodes Properties
//Output True
alert("Checking Child Nodes: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].hasChildNodes);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using an ActiveX object to do the parsing, it is only available in IE browsers. Since you are loading XML from a file, ry using XMLHttpRequest instead. It is implemented in IE since version 7 along with chrome, firefox, safari etc.
Here is a good explanation and some democode for you:
http://wordsfromgeek.blogspot.se/2008/11/xml-dom-in-chrome.html?m=1

Comment: If you look in the developer toolbar under console, what errormessage does it give you?

Comment: please see the attached image

Comment: That is the security message you get since you are loading a local file, it is not an error. Look at the answer in this post to allow loading of local files with ActiveX: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/to-help-protect-your-security-internet-explorer/eb59ac1c-f6c7-4f3f-b21d-116345cf5e79?msgId=7cf9a6c0-c60b-407f-aa39-d13c1ea6718d